# Magento 2 : admin URI gets duplicated

Tags: magento2.2, url, url-rewrite, dashboard

Today I finally was able to migrate magento.

Now, I wanted to check out the admin dashboard and for some readon, URI is being duplicated:

```
https://server.com/storename/admin/admin/index/index/key/22bc84d074958907a7499f...
```

I already tried:

```
  bin/magento --backend-frontname=admin
```

But the result is the same.

The rest of the store (so far) seems to be working without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the correct url structure for the admin panel dashboard. Unlike Magento 1, the admin panel URI consists of 4 segments instead of 3.

Answer (score 0):

It's correct URL of the Admin in Magento 2.x. If your admin URL is something different like

https://server.com/storename/admin_r2sxkn

then it will be like

https://server.com/storename/admin_r2sxkn/admin/index/index/key/22bc84d074958907a7499f...